# When I try to add new account for google analytic it doesn't take my project from firebase for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics

When I try to create account with google analytic it shows me error like this: **"This Firebase project is already connected to an Analytics account. In order to connect it to this account, you must first disconnect it from its current Analytics account."**
 I already delete it by following these steps.

1.Click Admin.

2.In the ACCOUNT column, use the menu to select the account you want to delete.

3.In the ACCOUNT column, click Account Settings.

But shows same error.

Here is the screenshot for the same.

[image]